# Sum the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\{\coth (n\pi x) + x^{2}\coth(n\pi/x)\}/n^{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This sum is from Ramanujan's letters to G. H. Hardy and Ramanujan gives the summation formula as
\begin{align} &\frac{1}{1^{3}}\left(\coth \pi x + x^{2}\coth\frac{\pi}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{2^{3}}\left(\coth 2\pi x + x^{2}\coth\frac{2\pi}{x}\right) \notag\\
&\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, + \frac{1}{3^{3}}\left(\coth 3\pi x + x^{2}\coth\frac{3\pi}{x}\right) + \cdots\notag\\
&\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, = \frac{\pi^{3}}{90x}(x^{4} + 5x^{2} + 1)\notag
\end{align}
Since $$\coth x = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{e^{x} - e^{-x}} = \frac{1 + e^{-2x}}{1 - e^{-2x}} = 1 + 2\frac{e^{-2x}}{1 - e^{-2x}}$$the above sum is transformed into $$(1 + x^{2})\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}} + 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2n\pi x}}{n^{3}(1 - e^{-2n\pi x})} + 2x^{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2n\pi/x}}{n^{3}(1 - e^{-2n\pi/x})}$$ If we put $q = e^{-\pi x}$ we get sums like $\sum q^{2n}/\{n^{3}(1 - q^{2n})\}$ which I don't know how to sum.

It seems I am going on a wrong track. Please provide some alternative approach.

**Update**: All the answers given below so far use complex analyis (transforms and residues) to evaluate the sum. I am almost certain that Ramanujan did not evaluate the sum using complex analysis. Perhaps the method by Ramanujan is more like the one explained in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898955/sum-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-1n-2n-17-cosh2n-1-pi-sq). Do we have any approach based on real-analysis only?

Comment: The series you get at the end look like [Lambert series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series), which have known resummation properties. But there's not an obvious multiplicative function in there.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I am aware of some standard results in Lambert series, but Ramanujan's results are so non-obvious in general that I am really unable to proceed here using the  Lambert series.

Comment: Something odd: If you take $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, then the LHS of the initial identity essentially picks up a factor of $1/x^2$ but the RHS picks up a factor of $x^2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical: you are right. Maybe its a typo and I need to replace $90x^3$ by $90x$. I will double check and edit.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I have obtained this problem from collected papers of Ramanujan and the same typo is there too. I will correct it here.

Comment: With that corrected form, the identity can be expressed suggestively as $f(x)+f(x^{-1})=\pi^3/18$ where $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{\coth n\pi x}{x}-\frac{\pi^3}{90x^2}.$$ (Notably, that $f(x)$ is analytic at zero.) So all one 'should' need do is prove that $f(x)+f(x^{-1})$ is constant, and then compute any particular value. Not sure how easy that is to actually accomplish...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17471/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-paramanand-singh).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recall the well known Mittag-Leffler expansion of hyperbolic cotangent function (denote $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$) :

> $$\sum_{m\in\mathbb{W}}\frac{1}{m^2+z^2}=\frac{\pi\coth\pi z}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}\tag{ML}$$

Hence, your sum is by its symmetry :

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{W}}\{\coth (n\pi x) + x^{2}\coth(n\pi/x)\}/n^{3} \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{W}}\left(\frac{1}{n^4}+\sum_{m\in\mathbb{W}}\frac{x^2/n^2}{m^2+n^2x^2}\right)
+\left(\frac{x^4}{n^4}+\sum_{m\in\mathbb{W}}\frac{x^2/n^2}{m^2+n^2/x^2}\right)\tag{1}\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\left(\zeta(4)+x^4\zeta(4)+\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb{W}^2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}\frac{1}{m^2+n^2x^2}+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\frac{1}{m^2+n^2/x^2}\right)\tag{2}\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\left(2\zeta(4)+2x^4\zeta(4)+x^2\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{W}^2}\frac{1}{n^2m^2}\frac{m^2+n^2x^2}{m^2+n^2x^2}\right)\tag{3}\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\left(2\zeta(4)+2x^4\zeta(4)+4x^2\zeta^2(2)\right)\tag{4}\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\left(2\frac{\pi^4}{90}+2x^4\frac{\pi^4}{90}+4x^2\frac{\pi^4}{36}\right)\tag{5}\\ \\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{90x}\left(1+x^4+5x^2\right)
\end{align}$$

**Explanations**

$(1)$ Use the Mittag-Leffler formula (ML) with $z=nx$ and $z=n/x$

$(2,4)$ Recall $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^s$

$(3)$ In the second sum rename $n \longleftrightarrow m$

$(5)$ Zetas for $s=2$ and $4$ are well known, i.e. $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ and $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$

Comment: This one appears to be simplest and very direct. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh At least it is a method not involving complex analysis at all since even ML formula could be obtained by using noncomplex methods, for example performing fourier expansion of the function $f(x)=\cosh ax$ on the interval $x\in\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$, as in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1843540/240067). By the way by the same argument is [$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\big(\pi n\sqrt2\big)-\sin\big(\pi n\sqrt2\big)}{n^3\Big({\cosh\big(\pi n\sqrt2}\big)-\cos\big(\pi n\sqrt2\big)\Big)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867127/240067) found in closed form.

Comment: @Machinato Nice derivation, is your proof unique or did you read this somewhere?

Comment: @BooleanWick I came with it on my own. But with almost everything in math, it is possible that somebody else has found this proof as well.

Answer (score 24):

It seems  to have escaped attention  that this sum  may be evaluated
using harmonic summation techniques.

Put $$S(x) = \zeta(3) + 
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{-1+\coth(n\pi x)}{n^3}$$
and introduce the sum
$$T(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{-1+\coth(n\pi x)}{n^3}.$$

The sum term is harmonic and  may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin
transform. We will construct a functional equation for $T(x).$

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{k^3}, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = 2\frac{e^{-2\pi x}}{1-e^{-2\pi x}}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$2 \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi x}}{1-e^{-2\pi x}} x^{s-1} dx
\\ = 2 \int_0^\infty \sum_{q\ge 1} e^{-2q\pi x} x^{s-1} dx
=  2 \sum_{q\ge 1} \int_0^\infty e^{-2q\pi x} x^{s-1} dx 
\\= 2 \Gamma(s) \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2\pi q)^s}
= \frac{2}{2^s} \frac{1}{\pi^s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s).$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$T(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = 
\frac{2}{2^s} \frac{1}{\pi^s} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \zeta(s+3)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^3} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \zeta(s+3)$$
for $\Re(s) > -2.$

The Mellin inversion integral here is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate  by shifting it to the left  for an expansion about
zero.

Fortunately the  trivial zeros of  the two zeta function  terms cancel
the poles of  the gamma function term. Shifting to  $\Re(s) = -3 -1/2$
we get
$$T(x)
= \frac{\pi^3 x^3}{90}
+ 4\zeta'(-2)\pi^2 x^2
+ \frac{\pi^3 x}{18}
- \zeta(3) 
+ \frac{\pi^3}{90x}
+ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-7/2-i\infty}^{-7/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

Substitute $s = -2 - t$ in the remainder integral to get
$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2+i\infty}^{3/2-i\infty}
\frac{2}{2^{-2-t}} 
\frac{1}{\pi^{-2-t}} \Gamma(-2-t) \zeta(-2-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^{t+2} dt$$
which is
$$\frac{x^2}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
2^{3+t} \pi^{2+t} \Gamma(-2-t) \zeta(-2-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^t dt.$$

In view of  the desired functional equation we  now use the functional
equation  of the Riemann  zeta function  on $Q(s)$  to prove  that the
integrand of the last integral is in fact $-Q(t).$

Start with the functional equation
$$\zeta(1-s) = \frac{2}{2^s\pi^s} 
\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
and substitute this into $Q(s)$ to obtain
$$Q(s) = 
\frac{2}{2^s} \frac{1}{\pi^s} 
\frac{\zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^s}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(s+3)
=  \frac{\zeta(3+s)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(1-s).$$
Apply the functional equation again (this time to $\zeta(s+3)$) to get
$$Q(s) =  \frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\frac{2}{2^{-2-s} \pi^{-2-s}}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi (-2-s)}{2}\right)
\Gamma(-2-s) \zeta(-2-s) \zeta(1-s)$$
Observe that
$$\frac{\cos\left(-\pi-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
= - \frac{\cos\left(-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)} = -1$$ so we finally get
$$Q(s) =  
- 2^{3+s} \pi^{2+s} \Gamma(-2-s) \zeta(-2-s) \zeta(1-s),$$
thus proving the claim.

We have established the functional equation
$$T(x)
= \frac{\pi^3 x^3}{90}
+ 4\zeta'(-2)\pi^2 x^2
+ \frac{\pi^3 x}{18}
- \zeta(3) 
+ \frac{\pi^3}{90x}
- x^2 T(1/x).$$

Finally returning to the sum that  was the initial goal we see that it
has the value $$\zeta(3) + T(x) + x^2 (\zeta(3) + T(1/x))$$
or
$$\zeta(3) + T(x) + x^2 \zeta(3) + x^2 T(1/x).$$
Using the functional equation for $T(x)$ this becomes
$$\zeta(3) + T(x) + x^2 \zeta(3) +
\frac{\pi^3 x^3}{90}
+ 4\zeta'(-2)\pi^2 x^2
+ \frac{\pi^3 x}{18}
- \zeta(3) 
+ \frac{\pi^3}{90x}
- T(x)$$ which is
$$x^2 \zeta(3)
+ \frac{\pi^3 x^3}{90}
+ 4\zeta'(-2)\pi^2 x^2
+ \frac{\pi^3 x}{18}
+ \frac{\pi^3}{90x}.$$

The inspiration for this calculation is from the paper "Mellin Transform and its Applications" by Szpankowski.

**Addendum.**
In view of the fact that $$\zeta(3) + 4\zeta'(-2)\pi^2 =0 $$ 
(consult e.g. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html))
this finally becomes
$$\frac{\pi^3 x^3}{90}
+ \frac{\pi^3 x}{18}
+ \frac{\pi^3}{90x}
= \frac{\pi^3}{90x}
\left(x^4 + 5x^2 + 1\right).$$

**Addendum II.** There is another functional equation of a harmonic sum at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991066/), this one somewhat more advanced.

Comment: Interesting solution and interesting reference (+1)

Comment: Do we have any approach based on real-analysis only? See the update in my question.

Comment: A theorem that I became aware of through posts on MSE is the [Ramanujan Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem). This would seem to indicate a profound understanding of Mellin transform methods.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: It appears that although Ramanujan does not use complex analysis explicitly, but has deep conception of some powerful results which can be obtained via complex analytic methods. Seen from that perspective perhaps your answer is closer to what Ramanujan might have done. I will accept it.

Answer (score 15):

Following in the same manner as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/949365)...

We are going to use the contour integral
$$
\oint\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi z}{\pi x}\right)\left(\frac{\coth(z)}{z^3}-\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{3z^2}\right)\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{1}
$$
where the contours of interest are, for real $R\to\infty$ and integer $n\to\infty$,
$$
\small\textstyle\color{#00A000}{[R,-R]+(n+\frac12)\pi i}\cup\color{#C00000}{-R+(n+\frac12)\pi i[1,-1]}\cup\color{#00A000}{[-R,R]-(n+\frac12)\pi i}\cup\color{#C00000}{R+(n+\frac12)\pi i[-1,1]}
$$
The integral along the red paths becomes negligible as $R\to\infty$. Along the upper green path, where $\mathrm{Im}(z)\approx+\infty$, $\cot(z)\approx-i$. Along the lower green path, where $\mathrm{Im}(z)\approx-\infty$, $\cot(z)\approx+i$. Since $\coth(z+\frac\pi2i)=\tanh(z)$, the integral along each of the green paths tends to $0$. Therefore, the full integral is $0$.

Since
$$
\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi z}{\pi x}\right)\text{ has residue }\pi x\text{ at }z=\pi nx\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\coth(z)}{z^3}-\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{3z^2}=-\frac1{45}+O(z^2)\text{ at }z=0\tag{3}
$$
the contribution from the singularities on the real axis is
$$
2\pi i\cdot\pi x\left[2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\coth(\pi nx)}{(\pi nx)^3}-\frac1{(\pi nx)^4}-\frac1{3(\pi nx)^2}\right)-\frac1{45}\right]\tag{4}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{\coth(z)}{z^3}\text{ has residue }\frac1{(\pi in)^3}\text{ at }z=\pi i n\text{ for }n\ne0\tag{5}
$$
and
$$
\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi z}{\pi x}\right)=-\pi i\coth\left(\frac{\pi n}{x}\right)\text{ at }z=\pi in\tag{6}
$$
the contribution from the singularities on the imaginary axis is
$$
2\pi i\left[2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac\pi{x^3}\frac{\coth\left(\frac{\pi n}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi n}{x}\right)^3}\right]\tag{7}
$$
Combining $(1)$, $(4)$, and $(7)$, yields
$$
x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\coth(\pi nx)}{(\pi nx)^3}+\frac1{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\coth\left(\frac{\pi n}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi n}{x}\right)^3}
=\frac{\zeta(4)}{\pi^4x^2}+\frac{\zeta(2)}{3\pi^2}+\frac{x^2}{90}\tag{8}
$$
Multiplying by $\pi^3x$ to match the question, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\coth(\pi nx)+x^2\coth(\pi n/x)}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{90x}\left(1+5x^2+x^4\right)\tag{9}
$$

Comment: Seems to be a good day for me to see interesting solutions! (+1)

Comment: Thanks robjohn. This seems simpler than the other answer from Marko. +1

Comment: Do we have any approach based on real-analysis only? See the update in my question.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another approach using contour integration is to integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot (\pi z) \coth (\pi x z)}{z^{3}} $$ around a circle centered at the origin that avoids the poles on the real and imaginary axes.

If we let the radius of the circle go to infinity discretely, the integral will vanish.

So summing the residues,  we get $$2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth (n \pi x)}{n^{3}} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cot (\frac{in \pi}{x})}{x(\frac{in}{x})^{3}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cot (-\frac{i n \pi}{x})}{x (-\frac{in}{x} )^{3}} + \text{Res}[f(z),0] =  0,$$

which implies

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth (n \pi x)}{n^{3}} + x^{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\frac{n \pi}{x})}{n^{3}} = - \frac{1}{2} \ \text{Res} [f(z),0]. $$

Expanding at the origin, we get

$$ \begin{align} \small f(z) &= \frac{\pi}{z^{3}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi z} - \frac{2 \zeta(2)}{\pi} z-\frac{2 \zeta(4)}{\pi} z^{3}  + \mathcal{O}(z^{5})\right) \left(\frac{1}{\pi (xz)} + \frac{2 \zeta(2)}{\pi} (xz) - \frac{2 \zeta(4)}{\pi} (xz)^{3} + \mathcal{O}(z^{5}) \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi x} \frac{1}{z^{5}} + \frac{2 \zeta(2) x^{2}-2 \zeta(2)}{\pi x} \frac{1}{z^{3}}  {\color{red}{-\frac{2 \zeta(4) x^{4}+4 \zeta(2)^{2} x^{2} + 2 \zeta(4)}{\pi x}}} \frac{1}{z} + \mathcal{O}(z) .\end{align}  $$

Therefore,  $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth (n \pi x)}{n^{3}} + x^{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\frac{n \pi}{x})}{n^{3}} = \frac{\zeta(4) x^{4}+2 \zeta(2)^{2} x^{2} + \zeta(4)}{\pi x} =\frac{\pi^{3}}{90x} \left( x^{4}+5x^{2}+1 \right). $$

Comment: Seems like I am getting simpler and simpler answers. +1

Comment: Do we have any approach based on real-analysis only? See the update in my question.

Comment: This works the same as my answer, except that $(3)$ and $(4)$ take the place of your expansion at the origin. (+1)