# Infinite sum solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

I was wondering if there is a closed form expression for the zeros of the following equation:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4 + x^2} \text{ where } x \in \rm I\!R$$

If it not exists, could you suggest a numerical method for calculate the approximate values of these zeros.

Thanks you in advance for every response!

Comment: Since for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ this is a series of positive terms, it is unclear how you expect there to be "zeros" of the expression (not an equation).

Comment: Totally agree with you, I've made a mistake writing the equation. My problem is there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693376/closed-form-solution-for-the-zeros-of-an-infinite-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384780/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n4a4/384839#384839) in which we determine that, for $a \gt 0$,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4+a^4} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2} \, a^3} \frac{\sinh{(\sqrt{2} \pi a)}+\sin{(\sqrt{2} \pi a)}}{\cosh{(\sqrt{2} \pi a)} -\cos{(\sqrt{2} \pi a)}}$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4+x^2} = \frac12 \left [ \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2 |x|^3} } \frac{\sinh{(\pi  \sqrt{2 |x|} )}+\sin{((\pi  \sqrt{2 |x|})}}{\cosh{((\pi  \sqrt{2 |x|})} -\cos{((\pi  \sqrt{2 |x|})}}- \frac1{x^2} \right ]  $$

Not sure how you expect to derive zeroes from the sum.