# Closed form solution for the zeros of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots, closed-form

Does there exist a closed form expression for the zeros of the following equation?

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4 - x^2} = 0 \text{ where } x \in \rm \mathbb R$$

Could you suggest a numerical method for calculate the approximate values of these zeros if that solution doesn't exist?

Comment: Strictly writing, you should add $=0$ in order to turn your expression into an EQUATION. ..

Answer (score 6):

If you decompose $\frac{1}{n^4 - x^2}$ into $\frac{1}{2x}(\frac{1}{n^2 - x} - \frac{1}{n^2 + x})$, and compute both series independently (everything converges absolutely, so it is OK to do so), you'd end up with an equation

$$\pi\sqrt{x}(\coth{\pi\sqrt{x}} + \cot{\pi\sqrt{x}}) = 2$$

which doesn't look promising for a closed form. It *might* be a good starting point for a numerical solution.

Comment: In that form Newton's method works reasonably well - it seems like convergence is quadratic.

Comment: Just a question: how do you compute the two series? Using the residue theorem or similar?

Comment: @AlessandroPalla No, I just happen to know them. They follow from Euler's infinite product representation of $\sin x$. Another way is a direct demonstration - see https://www-m9.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/WS2010/IMCSeminar/Cotangent.pdf for an inspirational example.

Comment: @AlessandroPalla It easy to understand that the equation $y(\coth y + \cot y) = 2$ has an infinite number of real solutions (for $k\in \mathbb Z_{\ge1}$, every interval $]\pi k,\pi(k+1)[$ will contain exactly one solution). To get their asymptotic form, we can note that for large $k$ we can replace $\coth y$ by $1$, so that $y_k\approx \pi k+\frac{3\pi}{4}$ with good precision.

Comment: For $\pi\sqrt x=z$:$$\text {coth}(z)+\cot(z)-z=0$$